# Compiler error when tikz nodes should be visible on non censecutive slides using temporal

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Using `temporal` it is possible to get a transitioning effect on one slide. The following example creates an error on one of the lines.

Essentially:

This does work: `node at (ONE)   [select on=<1>]{ONE}`

This does work: `node at (ONE)   [select on=<3>]{ONE}`

This does work: `node at (ONE)   [select on=<1-3>]{ONE}`

This does not work: `node at (ONE)   [select on=<1,3>]{ONE}`

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,times}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\newcommand{\magic}{1}
\newcommand{\interesting}{2}
\newcommand{\selected}{3}

\resizebox{0.485\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(ONE.base)}]
\tikzset{
    normal/.style={fill=white, align=center, draw},
    selected/.style={fill=orange, align=center, thick, draw},
    temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{\temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}},
    select on/.style={temporal=#1{normal}{selected}{normal}}
  }

\coordinate (ONE) at (0,0);
\coordinate (TWO) at (4,1);
\coordinate (THREE) at (8,-1);

\draw (ONE) -- (TWO) -- (THREE);

\draw
    %ERROR HERE
    node at (ONE)   [select on=<\magic,\selected>]{ONE}
    %node at (ONE)   [select on=<1,3>]{ONE} <- same error
    %node at (ONE)   [select on=<\magic>]{ONE} <- no error
    node at (TWO)   [select on=<\interesting>]{TWO}
    node at (THREE) [select on=<\selected>]{THREE}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.485\textwidth}
\scriptsize
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<\magic>
\textcolor{orange}{\emph{Magic}} -- 
The selected nodes are magic, the audience applaudes.

\onslide<\interesting>
\textcolor{orange}{\emph{Interesting}} -- 
The selected nodes are interesting, an author wrote a book.

\onslide<\selected>
\textcolor{orange}{\emph{Selected}} --
The selected nodes are selected. This may or may not be obvious.

\end{overprint}
\end{minipage}

%DO NOT INDENT THE END OF A FRAGILE FRAME
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To sort and present my data the way i want to i need the selections to show up multiple times in the presentation in different constellations.

How can i fix this in a way that gets `node at (ONE)   [select on=<\magic,\selected>]{ONE}` to work. Normal on all slides but 1 and 3 where the nodes show up as selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the comma inside the `<,>`, which confuses tikz parser which takes it as a key separator.

The solution is to enclose in braces that part, i.e:

```
\draw    
     node at (ONE)   [select on=<{\magic,\selected}>]{ONE}
     ...;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: nice, thanks - i was hoping for something like this.